# FMDB Crash: SEGV_MAPERR at [FMDatabaseQueue inDatabase:]

Tags: ios, multithreading, crash, fmdb, crittercism

I'm using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) in an iOS app. Recently I have received several crash reports from Apteligent about a crash of FMDB:

```
0   libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001810ab120 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 2904
!   1   myApp 0x00000001001ac840 -[FMDatabaseQueue inDatabase:] (FMDatabaseQueue.m:142)
    2   myApp 0x000000010011844c +[DataBaseController insert:withObjects:] (DataBaseController.m:602)
    3   myApp 0x0000000100118254 +[DataBaseController insertObjects:withObjects:] (DataBaseController.m:575)
    4   myApp 0x0000000100150e80 -[SendManagementBBDD crearySalvarEnvioConSolicitud:EntidadParaEncolar:borrarTrasEnvio:] (SendManagementBBDD.m:686)
    5   myApp 0x0000000100150a28 __76-[SendManagementBBDD sendEntitiesAfterDetail:OnComplete:]_block_invoke (SendManagementBBDD.m:615)
    6   libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001810a55f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
    7   libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001810b0b94 _dispatch_sync_f_invoke + 68
    8   myApp 0x0000000100150404 -[SendManagementBBDD sendEntitiesAfterDetail:OnComplete:] (SendManagementBBDD.m:563)
    9   myApp 0x000000010005c284 __44-[DetailVC startWork:]_block_invoke (DetailVC.m:286)
    10  libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001810a5630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
    11  libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001810a55f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
    12  libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001810b3a88 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2136
    13  libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001810b3224 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001812b9470 _pthread_wqthread + 1088
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001812b9020 start_wqthread + 0
```

I access to the database from multiple threads. [As the documentation says](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb#using-fmdatabasequeue-and-thread-safety), I have a single instance of FMDatabaseQueue and I share it across all the threads of the app. I'm getting a SEGV_MAPERR crash at the method [FMDatabaseQueue inDatabase:]

This crash happens hardly ever, but I would like to resolve it.
Any ideas what is causing it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Like your other question, this crash seems to be a part of your app code and not Crittercism SDK. If you still believe that this has been caused due to Crittercism, you can create a support ticket by sending an email to support@apteligent.com by mentioning the concerned App ID and the direct crash URL. Be noted that the email support is available for paid customers only.

Comment: I'm not saying that this crash is caused by Crittercism SDK. I wanted to say that I had received in Crittercism several reports about this crash. Sorry for the confusion.